# Getting object undefined when values are assigned

Tags: javascript

My function has a parameter `dtoIn` and I am trying to check if it's undefined or null.

I have values assigned like this so it shouldn't be undefined, but I get that the object is undefined anyway. Can I have some advise please.

```
{
    count : 10,
    minAge : 10,
    maxAge : 10,
}

function main(dtoIn={count, minAge, maxAge}) { 
  if (typeof dtoIn !== "undefined" && dtoIn !== null){
    alert(`empty`);
  }
}
```

Comment: That isn't a valid default value unless you're defining `count`, `minAge` and `maxAge` somewhere in the global scope. Also by defining a default value (if you do it correctly) `dtoIn` will never be undefined or null.

Comment: You need assign your object to a variable, right now you are creating an object and discarding it.

Comment: Even so, the default value in the function will throw errors. To make it valid you need to provide a valid default object `function main(dtoIn={count:10, minAge:10, maxAge:10}) {...`

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple of misunderstandings in your code as to how [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and [function default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) work.

Consider the following example:

```js
let obj = {
    count : 10,
    minAge : 10,
    maxAge : 10,
}

function main({ count = 15, minAge = 15, maxAge = 15 } = {}) {
    console.log(count, minAge, maxAge)
}

main(obj);
main();
```

We don't actually even need to perform any undefined checks here, because this [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#destructured_parameter_with_default_value_assignment) is for either destructuring a given object to count, minAge and maxAge OR if nothing is given, we destructure into count = 15, minAge = 15 and maxAge = 15.

If you want to keep the dtoIn named parameter and have default values for it, you can do that like so:

```js
let obj = {
    count : 10,
    minAge : 10,
    maxAge : 10,
}

function main(dtoIn = { count: 15, minAge: 15, maxAge: 15 }) {
    console.log(dtoIn);
}

main(obj);
main();
```

Comment: That's assuming their goal was to create separate variables in the function and not create a `dtoIn` object with keys/values from other variables...really hard to tell.

Comment: @vanowm Yeah. My approach here is to provide at least some kind of sensible solution, even if it isn't exactly what the asker wanted. Often times we have more or less confusing questions and people asking how to do something that is not even possible, because they have understood something wrong in the first place. So the only sensible thing to do is to offer some kind of "best guess" answer. :)

Comment: The only sensible thing is to vote to close for clarification. Providing a default object and destructuring are not necessarily interchangeable, though in this basic example they may be, plus you've now possibly compounded the OP's misunderstanding of defaults by combining it with destructuring and having to provide an empty default object in order to trigger the defaults in the destructuring.

Comment: @pilchard That's what the code of conduct tells us anyway. I've never really liked how sensitive we are to closing not-so-perfect questions, when there are often great opportunities to learn. We shouldn't gatekeep asking questions if you aren't able to perfectly describe the problem and can't offer an unambiguous example, be it because of slight problems regarding language barrier or technical understanding. I'd get your point if I hadn't provided links to documentation and explained what I did.

Comment: Then at least offer the most basic solution which is just to provide a valid object as default since there is no indication at all that the OP was attempting to destructure. If anything it strikes me as a misunderstanding of [object property shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)

Comment: @pilchard That I can do! :) I've edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're assigning function params wrong try this way

```
let dtoIn = {
count : 10,
minAge : 10,
maxAge : 10,
};

function main(val) { 
  if (typeof(val) == "undefined" && val !== null){
    alert("empty");
  }
}

main(dtoIn);
```